# I cannot read and write data in firebase with auth!= null rule in android studios

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have signed in but cannot read or write to the database.

Here are my rules:

```
{
   "rules": {
     "users": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
     }
   } 
}
```

Users in the rule are at the root node and the document under it is what I want to access but cannot. If anyone knows how can I access firebase data after login on to firebase with the above-mentioned rules please answer.

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");

            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    String phone = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber().substring(3);

                    if(snapshot.child(phone).child("state_on_app").equals("farmer")){
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "I am in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "I am in as a shop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

The code with which I am trying to access the Firebase Realtime Database but it's not working.

https://github.com/aouspi/firebase-json/blob/main/README.md

Comment: 1) Please show the code that doesn't work against these rules. 2) Also show the data that you're trying to access, as text instead of a screenshot (which means we can also more easily use it). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please check I have uploaded the code and have added an hyperlink of github repositiry where I have added the json file from firebase

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the following rules:

```
{
   "rules": {
     "users": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
     }
   } 
}
```

You try to allow the authenticated users to write and read data under the `users` node. However, in your code, you are trying to read data from:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
```

Which won't work. To solve this simply change:

```
.child("user")
```

Into:

```
.child("users")
```

See the "s"?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Good catch Alex. I voted to close the question as a typo.